# Given two SELECT statements, how to merge them to get one result minus the other?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to remove `UNwantedIDs` from `wantedIDs`, how to make sub-queries and get one result?

Here is my `UNwantedIDs` query:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId` ORDER BY `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId` ASC) UNwantedIDs
FROM `recipe_ingredient` 
WHERE `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
     IN(SELECT `ingredient`.`ingredientId` AS unlinkIng 
        FROM `ingredient` 
        WHERE `ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN(1) or `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN(1))
ORDER BY `recipeId` ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84f00/5

Here is my `wantedIDs` query:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId` ORDER BY `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId` ASC) wantedIDs
FROM `recipe_ingredient` 
WHERE `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
     IN(SELECT `ingredient`.`ingredientId` AS unlinkIng 
        FROM `ingredient` 
        WHERE `ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN(4,178) or    `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN(4,178))
ORDER BY `recipeId` ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84f00/4

Result ID like:

```
2,3,7,8,11,21,24,36,37,41,67,70,75,80,83,99,108
```

Comment: Any type of query i'm accept but i want result Above given IDs.

Comment: @halfer thank to help me yes sure next time i am use formatting tool as per you said . thanks

Comment: The queries look like they have the same structure. Have you tried just adding `(ingredient.ingredientId != 1 AND ingredient.linkIngredientPerent !=1)` to the second query?

Comment: but @halfer may be come there multiple instead of given 1 id than what i do  .

Comment: A detail that should be in your question! How about swapping the `!=` for `IN` then?

Comment: @halfer yes i want to use IN

Comment: Please let me know why you have rolled back my edit - this was essentially the addition of your comment thus: "but halfer may be come there multiple instead of given 1 id". If you want to put it in your own words, that's fine, but please put it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId`
        ORDER BY `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId` ASC
    ) wantedIDs
FROM `recipe_ingredient` 
WHERE `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
     IN(SELECT `ingredient`.`ingredientId` AS unlinkIng 
        FROM `ingredient` 
        WHERE
          (`ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN(4,178) OR
           `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN(4,178)
          )
      )
      AND `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId` NOT IN (
          SELECT 
          `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId`
             FROM `recipe_ingredient` 
          WHERE `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
               IN (SELECT `ingredient`.`ingredientId` AS unlinkIng 
                  FROM `ingredient` 
                  WHERE `ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN(1) OR
                       `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN(1)
               )
      )
ORDER BY `recipeId` ASC
```

This is the result of a `NOT IN` used to merge the two queries. It is rather slow at the moment, probably because you need to add some indexes.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84f00/16

Comment: You're welcome. My comments about rolling back other people's edits still stand though. Whilst it's still your question, if someone adds an improvement in, it is generally expected that you justify a rollback.